# Parallel.ForEach executes twice on start up only when code hasn't been run?

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

I'm working on a Windows Service that where I am attempting to use Parallel.ForEach to spawn unique timed threads. The problem is that if I leave the code alone for several hours in VS or if I stop the service for a few hours and start anything back up - the initial start up code executes twice. Here is a snippet from the static void that the service's OnStart is calling.

```
Parallel.ForEach(urls, url =>
                    {
                        PageGrabber pagegrab = new PageGrabber(url);
                        if (url.Type.ToLower() == "http")
                        {
                            pagegrab.Elapsed += (obj, e) =>
                                {
                                    pagegrab.CheckNormal();
                                };
                            pagegrab.CheckNormal();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            pagegrab.Elapsed += (obj, e) =>
                            {
                                pagegrab.CheckXML();
                            };
                            pagegrab.CheckXML();
                        }
                    }
                    );
```

This works great if I use Threads directly, but really wanted to update this code a bit. The duplicate execution happens immediately. The PageGrabber object is pretty simple in that it simply uses a WebClient to download either HTML or XML as a string - pretty boring.

Comment: Which part of the code you posted is “the initial start up code”? Or is that somewhere else?

Comment: The only parts missing are the part where it reads a text file containing urls and creates a "url" object with them. It's in a try catch block. Get the URLs, make a URL object, add it to a list of type URL and then the foreach loop - that's it. It's really basic which is what's got me going on this. It's also rather hard to debug since it only happens if nothing is touched for about 6 hours

Comment: Is the duplicate execution happening as a response to requests from multiple (almost) simultaneous threads?  Or does it happen in a controlled environment in response to a single request? i.e. are you sure the enclosing method isn't being called 2x?  I don't see anything in the posted code that would cause your problem.

Comment: As an example, I can open VS2010 and load the solution. Right-click the project and select "Debug" and the duplication occurs. No matter how many times I open/close, debug the project again, it doesn't happen until I've been away from the PC for about 6-8 hours. When running as a compiled service - the same holds true - but it's not consistent at all. I've stepped through the code in a debugger and added some additional logging statements and the only code duplicated is that which is called in the ForEach loop - very weird.

Comment: you should post a minimal complete program exposing the problem that you have. Reasoning on a partially available code is futile.

Comment: I replaced the foreach loop with a Task Array and it works fine. I appreciate all the comments and if I can get to a point where I can post an entire working example of the anomaly I will.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that you've subscribed to the `Elapsed` event by `pageGrabber.Elapsed +=...`
It is possible for that event to be raised or not.
So in some conditions if the event raised, your method will be called twice, otherwise it will be called once.

I don't think that you could resolve this problem by changing the parallel implementation (using task array instead of `Parallel.Foreach`). It just might cause the problem occur less often, which is a very bad symptom in parallel programming. You shouldn't let the problems to fade out by making their preconditions of happening harder! You should totally remove them!

Comment: I don't disagree - so any suggestions for alternatives for setting the elapsed event? In this scenario - the System.Timers.Timer in the object needs to operate on it's own Interval.

Comment: @kpcrash I don't have any idea about your PageGrabber class, and the responsibility of the Elapsed event.

Answer (score 0):

So mehrandvd was on the right path. When creating an instance of my class, that used a System.Timers.Timer, it was firing the Elapsed event immediately because the Interval property wasn't being set correctly. Thus:

```
pagegrab.Elapsed += (obj, e) =>
                        {
                            pagegrab.CheckXML();
                        };
                        pagegrab.CheckXML();
```

Caused duplicate execution when nothing had happened in a while because the instance of the class that had the Interval set correctly was no longer in memory. My stupidity - all fixed now. Thanks for all the comments and suggestions.